# Kernel tarball for 3.3.1

Tags: kernel

I use Ubuntu 12.04
I changed kernel version to 3.3.1.
Where can I find the kernel tarball? (to compile proprietary module)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All v3 kernel distributions can be found @ http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/